# How do I use MySQL variables in a SQL statement with Javascript/node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a MySQL query in javascript running through node that is throwing me an error.

When I print the queryString to the console and paste it in MySQL it works fine but when I print the err in the console it says there is a syntax error.

I think I have narrowed it down but I don't know why it's happening or how to get around it.

Here is the full SQL query:

```sql
set @csum := 0;
set @csum2 := 0;
set @csum3 := 0;
SELECT
    r.meeting_date,
    r.user_mode,
    (@csum:=@csum + r.total_profit) AS total_profit,
    (@csum2:=@csum2 + r.ev) AS ev,
    (@csum3:=@csum3 + r.bets) AS bets
FROM
    (SELECT
        meeting_date,
            user_mode,
            ROUND(SUM(profit)) AS total_profit,
            ROUND(SUM(bsp_profit)) AS total_bsp_profit,
            ROUND(SUM(est_ev)) AS ev,
            SUM(win) AS wins,
            COUNT(race_id) AS bets,
            ROUND(SUM(win) / COUNT(race_id), 2) * 100 AS hit_rate,
            ROUND(SUM(profit) / COUNT(race_id), 2) AS ppr,
            ROUND((SUM(win) / COUNT(race_id)) / (COUNT(race_id) / SUM(num_runners)), 2) AS iv
    FROM
        qs_historic_races
    WHERE
        user_mode = 1
    GROUP BY meeting_date , user_mode) AS r
ORDER BY meeting_date;
```

If I remove the variables and remove the cumulative sums then it works fine - but the query is no good without them - so removing these rows:

```
set @csum := 0;
set @csum2 := 0;
set @csum3 := 0;

(@csum:=@csum + r.total_profit) AS total_profit,
(@csum2:=@csum2 + r.ev) AS ev,
(@csum3:=@csum3 + r.bets) AS bets
```

Here is the entire error that is printed:

```
0|server   |    'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'set @csum2 := 0;\nset @csum3 := 0;\nSELECT\n    r.meeting_date,\n    r.user_mode,\n  \' at line 2',
0|server   |   sqlState: '42000',
0|server   |   index: 0,
0|server   |   sql:
0|server   |    'set @csum := 0;\nset @csum2 := 0;\nset @csum3 := 0;\nSELECT\n    r.meeting_date,\n    r.user_mode,\n    (@csum:=@csum + r.total_profit) AS total_profit,\n    (@csum2:=@csum2 + r.ev) AS ev,\n    (@csum3:=@csum3 + r.bets) AS bets\nFROM\n    (SELECT\n        meeting_date,\n            user_mode,\n            ROUND(SUM(profit)) AS total_profit,\n            ROUND(SUM(bsp_profit)) AS total_bsp_profit,\n            ROUND(SUM(est_ev)) AS ev,\n            SUM(win) AS wins,\n            COUNT(race_id) AS bets,\n            ROUND(SUM(win) / COUNT(race_id), 2) * 100 AS hit_rate,\n            ROUND(SUM(profit) / COUNT(race_id), 2) AS ppr,\n            ROUND((SUM(win) / COUNT(race_id)) / (COUNT(race_id) / SUM(num_runners)), 2) AS iv\n    FROM\n        qs_historic_races\n    WHERE\n        user_mode = 1\n    GROUP BY meeting_date , user_mode) AS r\nORDER BY meeting_date;' }
```

I've been scratching my head for hours with this so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the \n and everything works just fine.

```
set @csum := 0;set @csum2 := 0;set @csum3 := 0;SELECT    r.meeting_date,    r.user_mode,    (@csum:=@csum + r.total_profit) AS total_profit,    (@csum2:=@csum2 + r.ev) AS ev,    (@csum3:=@csum3 + r.bets) AS bets FROM    (SELECT        meeting_date,            user_mode,            ROUND(SUM(profit)) AS total_profit,            ROUND(SUM(bsp_profit)) AS total_bsp_profit,            ROUND(SUM(est_ev)) AS ev,            SUM(win) AS wins,            COUNT(race_id) AS bets,            ROUND(SUM(win) / COUNT(race_id), 2) * 100 AS hit_rate,            ROUND(SUM(profit) / COUNT(race_id), 2) AS ppr,            ROUND((SUM(win) / COUNT(race_id)) / (COUNT(race_id) / SUM(num_runners)), 2) AS iv    FROM        qs_historic_races    WHERE       user_mode = 1    GROUP BY meeting_date , user_mode) AS r ORDER BY meeting_date;
```

Comment: Apologies, I have only started using javascript a few days ago, can you tell me how I do that?
I thought that and so I tried using `queryString.replace("\r?\n|?\t|\\s+", '')` but it didn't seem to work

Comment: I wrote it out as one long string and I got a syntax error but slightly different
`(@c\' at line 1',`
So I don't think it likes this line of SQL
`set @csum2 := 0;`

Comment: I don't know where you get your mysql string but with **str.replace(/\\n|\\t|\\r/g, " ");** you can remove all single occurrence of unwanted character, please use a **space** for replacing, because it will give you an error message otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was because it's treating the set `@csum := 0;` as a separate query.
I've rewritten the query without the set variables and it works